# socket descriptor per thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

As I understand, in Linux (not sure about `Unix` in general) there exists a single table of file  descriptors per process, and the table is shared among all threads.

So, does this mean that any socket FD created in a thread will become available to other threads in the process?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's what "shared among all threads" means.

Comment: For instance, a server might have a main thread that accepts incoming connections, and a pool of worker threads that process the data on the connections. The worker threads need to have access to the sockets accepted by the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and in fact this is true of POSIX threads in general.  File descriptors and "open file descriptions" are per-process.

Comment: It's true of Posix *processes*. It doesn't really have anything to do with threads at all.